# Perform to or with?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

If I want to know whether someone performs an activity with someone, which preposition should I use to ask them?

1. Do you perform it *to* them?
2. Do you perform it *with* them?

Comment: Careful with the tenses. Do you perform = an usual or ongoing thing. Do you perform this activity every time you see them? Perform something FOR someone. Your use sounds more like acting or music playing.

Answer (score 1):

A way to think of this would be to put it in the context of a play.

- You perform the play **with** other actors.
- You perform the play **to** an audience.

Answer (score 0):

“To” means “in that direction”, literally (“I am going to Boston”) or figuratively (“I am giving the job to Bob”).

“With” means “alongside”, as in “coffee with cream“ or “I performed with him”.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the performance.

Take the case of initiation rites into the Dionysian Mysteries around the time of the eruption of Mount Vesuvius.  We have evidence that this was performed *with* others.